# Positive slope with negative values

Tags: algebra-precalculus, slope

When I was in school I learned that slope could be found with the following:
$$m=\frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1}$$
When given the coordinates $(-3, 0)$ and $(0, 5)$, plotting these points on a Cartesian plane shows a positive slope, but using the slope equation:
$$m=\frac{5-0}{0-3}$$
$$m=\frac5{-3}$$
where a positive divided by a negative is a negative value and thus negative slope.

*I realize the correct slope is $\frac53$*. But why is the formula we learned in grade school breaking down here? Am I making some obvious mistake or what? I'm trying to help a young student with Algebra and I'm not sure how to explain how I arrive at $\frac53$ other than "I just know". Help is appreciated.

Comment: $0-(-3)=3$ for your calculation of $x_2-x_1$

Comment: Got it :). Thank you, what a blunder on my part!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You copied the sign incorrectly; the correct calculation is
$$m=\frac{5-0}{0-(-3)}=\frac53$$

Comment: oh dear, how obvious. Thank you very much.